# Benchmark for android and windows(32-bit)

Tags: java, windows, arm, benchmarking

Is there a known CPU benchmark that tests the same things on either platform? If not, what kinds of benchmarks should be tested on them? (I plan to make applications for both if one does not exist)

Comment: What do you want to benchmark, and why?

Comment: CPU performance in top ARM (Cortex A9's specifically) CPUs and in top Atom CPUs. I want to demonstrate approximate performance figures for each platform to show my peers where ARM is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quadrant](http://www.aurorasoftworks.com/products/quadrant) is one famous benchmarking tool which is used for Android phones! Apart from CPU benchmarking it does I/O and Graphics benchmarking as well. Here is the [link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard&hl=en) to the Android app.

I've worked on these apps on ARM based phones, so I can suggest you a few things. Benchmarking is NOT the absolute measure of how well a phone/device performs. Just because you get a higher benchamarking value doesn't mean higher performance. Total device performance doesn't depend on CPU speed alone. Cache size, Bus speed, RAM size etc all contribute to the overall performance.

Also, I myself have seen companies modifying their code in order to fool famous benchmarking tools! So don't *exclusively* rely on the benchmarked values. They should just serve as a reference for you!

Non-technically, one thing benchmarking helps is to flaunt your device with your friends :)

Comment: I know exactly what you're saying, but these benchmarks aren't the whole purpose of my project; it's just a little extra info for my peers. There are way too many factors involved in benchmarking both platforms to conclude that one's CPU is "better" than another. They have different instruction sets and work differently on different tasks. So yeah, obviously it'll be hard to get meaningful performance measures, but I was basically looking for something with the same algorithm/s, cross-platform, maybe just providing MIPS or DMIPS...or something. Thanks though.